# How to get JWT payload from different key rather than req.user in NestJS

Tags: jwt, nestjs, passport.js, passport-jwt, nestjs-jwt

The way to get payload after the guard is like what [this tutorial](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implement-protected-route-and-jwt-strategy-guards) mentioned.

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Get('profile')
getProfile(@Request() req) {
  return req.user;
}
```

Basically, you can access the payload with the object key `user` in the request.

But I'd like to know how to store this payload in another key. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you should define a decorator file for getting user:

```
export const getUser = createParamDecorator (
    ( data:unknown , ctx:ExecutionContext) => {
        const request=ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        return request.user;
    }
)
```

and use it in controller like this:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Get('profile')
getProfile(@getUser() user:User) {

}
```

you can find documentation here: https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators